# Cron job for PHP yiic command

Tags: php, yii, cron, yiic

I have created a php yiic command as

```
class StartCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

  public function run($params){
    Yii::log("Cron Job has started");        
  }
}
```

When I run the command `php yiic Start`, I get the result in the log.

And I have add this to the crontab

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path/app/console/commands/StartCommand.php
```

But the job is not running.
I think I have to mention the php yiic Start to the crontab.

But where do I add it ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
* * * * * cd /path/app/console/commands && php yiic Start
```

Comment: @ Ajey : You add it to the crontab and you use the format that Loic gave you.

Comment: and when I save the crontab, its saving in /tmp/crontab.mek265/crontab. Is this correct?

Comment: That's strange. A way to do crontabs is by editing the file `/etc/crontab` (on most linux distributions)

Comment: In /etc I have the following things
cron.d/       cron.daily/   cron.hourly/  cron.monthly/ crontab       cron.weekly/
In which one should I write this job?

Comment: just run a `crontab -e` it should work on most distributions. I am not sure who the owner of the /etc/crontab file is or if you should edit it directly. If it is run by the root then you might have problems with access. It is best to use a user that is in the apache group (or the group that runs apache).

Comment: @Loïc please help me if you can. thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423084/yii-how-to-call-url-with-yiic