# Yii - How to access to model and call action in yiic

Tags: yii, cron, yiic

I have an action that prints "Hello World":

```
public function actionStart()
{
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

I will to run a cron job that calls this action every minute.

How I can do this with yiic ?

---

## UPDATE:

I create console app. I have cron.php inside index.php:

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

// including Yii
require_once('framework/yii.php');

// we'll use a separate config file
$configFile='protected/config/c.php';

// creating and running console application
Yii::createConsoleApplication($configFile)->run();
```

and config/c.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    // This path may be different. You can probably get it from `config/main.php`.
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'Cron',

    'preload'=>array('log'),

    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),
    // We'll log cron messages to the separate files
    'components'=>array(
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'logFile'=>'cron.log',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'logFile'=>'cron_trace.log',
                    'levels'=>'trace',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        // Your DB connection
        'db'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbConnection',
            // …
        ),
    ),
);
```

and protected/commands/MyCommand.php:

```
<?php
class MyCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args)
    {
        $logs = Log::model()->findAll();
        print_r($logs);
        die();
    }
}
```

when I run this:

```
$ ./protected/yiic my
```

I got this error:

```
PHP Error[2]: include(Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    in file /path/to/app/folder/framework/YiiBase.php at line 427
#0 /path/to/app/folder/framework/YiiBase.php(427): autoload()
#1 unknown(0): autoload()
#2 /path/to/app/folder/protected/commands/MyCommand.php(6): spl_autoload_call()
#3 /path/to/app/folder/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): MyCommand->run()
#4 /path/to/app/folder/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run()
#5 /path/to/app/folder/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#6 /path/to/app/folder/framework/yiic.php(33): CConsoleApplication->run()
#7 /path/to/app/folder/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once()
#8 /path/to/app/folder/protected/yiic(3): require_once()
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Have you configured your `console.php` instead of `main.php` ?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour This is necessary? I set config file in  `$configFile='protected/config/c.php';`

Comment: `CConsoleCommand` uses console.php config file instead of main.php

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I configured `console.php` and again i got that error

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a command: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#creating-commands

Then you can acess your function by running this command:
    yiic yourCommand start

Answer (score 1):

You have to load your models in Console application.

Open `console.php` configuration file, and add this line under the line `'name'=>'My Console Application',`

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*'
    ),
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your don't have such 'log.php' file you are including.

maybe try this from console :

```
touch /path/to/app/folder/protected/log.php
```

You should have another error message then (or it will run smoothly).

Comment: Log is my model. I will try to use models in console

Answer (score -1):

Just open your yiic.php file check framework path in it.